# laravel goutte node list is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, goutte

I have a problem with goutte,some of the content have images while some don't and in case there isn't any image I want it to ignore that and keep going on without saving the image but if there is, save it.

```
$crawler->filter('div[id=content]>.teaser-50')->each(function ($node, $key) {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        if(!empty ($link_r = $link->getUri())) {
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        }
        $id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
        // if news is null
        if (!$news) {
            $news = new News();
        }
        $news->title = $title;
        $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
        $news->description = $description;
        $news->link = $link_r;
        $news->image = $image_path;
        $news->save();
        $this->info('Scraping done succesfully');
    });
```

at the moment I have output:

```
λ php artisan scrape:news
Scraping done succesfully
Scraping done succesfully
Scraping done succesfully
Scraping done succesfully


  [InvalidArgumentException]
  The current node list is empty.
```

current node list is empty occurs on the first news which doesn't have a image, how can this be solved?

Comment: Wrap it in a try catch block if you want to just move past it. You can instruct the scraper to navigate elsewhere if thats the end of the new gallery.

Comment: any code example?

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
        $title = $node->filter('.plain')->text();
        $datepublished = $node->filter('.dateonline')->text();
        $description = $node->filter('.teaser-link')->text();
        $link = $node->filter('a')->link();
        if(!empty ($link_r = $link->getUri())) {
        $image = $node->filter('img')->image();
        $image_s = $image->getUri();
        $filename = basename($image_s);
        $image_path = ('news-gallery/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image_s)->save(public_path('news-gallery/' . $filename));
        }
        $id = 1+ $key + 1;
        $news = News::where('id', $id)->first();
        // if news is null
        if (!$news) {
            $news = new News();
        }
        $news->title = $title;
        $news->datepublished = $datepublished;
        $news->description = $description;
        $news->link = $link_r;
        $news->image = $image_path;
        $news->save();
        $this->info('Scraping done succesfully');
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        // do something else when the error occurs...
        // go to a different page?
        // scrape different elements?
}
```

Comment: Then your exception is coming from somewhere else. Try wrapping more code  with the try catch and seeing where it fails.